# Получить градиент картинки

Tags: html, css, scss

Есть кнопка с градиентом:

[image: картинка]

Мне нужно ее преобразовать в `<button>` с css градиентом для удобства работы. Пробовал методом тыка подобрать градиент, но ничего не получилось.

Answer (score -1):

Слава богу живем не в 2011, хотя тогда вроде существовали подобные инструменты. Или нет? Там можете и фото загрузить.

https://cssgradient.io/

Comment: Ответ-ссылка. Не стоит публиковать ссылки как ответ, во-первых, они могут перестать работать, во-вторых, по указанной ссылке нет решения на ответ, там есть только градиент, так что этот "ответ", лучше стоит опубликовать как комментарий т.к. он по факту не даёт решения как создать кнопку как на картинке.